# SCCM Powershell - Retrieving a "lazy" property

Tags: powershell, deployment, properties, schedule, sccm

Let's say I run:

Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "gar25*" | select CollectionName, ApplicationName, PackageID, DeploymentTime, EnforcementDeadline | out-gridview

[image]

This gives me all the info I need on multiple deployments associated to a user, but the value "EnforcementDeadline" is blank, which i'm guessing is a lazy property.
How would I retrieve it? I have found this article:

https://trevorsullivan.net/2010/09/28/powershell-configmgr-wmi-provider-feat-lazy-properties/#comment-3628074206

but i'm really struggling to adapt the code.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Even if i do something else like : "Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "abc123*"" on the server it returns similar information. deployment time, modification...but no required and/or expiring, what the...?

Comment: Haha this is driving me nuts...even on the assignement, if i do for example: 
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName XXXX-Namespace  "ROOT\SMS\site_XXX" -Query "SELECT * FROM SMS_Advertisement WHERE ProgramName='XXXXX'"  I see the ExpirationTime but not Required...wow!

Comment: Just because PowerShell doesn't output a property by default doesn't mean that the object does not contain the property.

Comment: How do i extract/display that property ? @Bill_Stewart

Comment: Even if i do for example :
"Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "abc" | Format-List -Property * | out-file c:\temp\res.txt" I get a ton of other properties but not the assigned / required time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnforcementDeadline` is a property for application deployments. You're trying to read it from a package deployment where it doesn't exist because they can have multiple assigned schedules which can be both one time or recurring (ex. daily). If you use `Get-CMApplicationDeployment` and `Get-CMPackageDeployment` you will get the right type of objects so you can access the values.

I've included a sample that will detect if the deployment is for a package and retrieve the `StartTime`-values for it's schedules (I assume they are non-reccuring).

```
$DeadlineColumn = @{
    Name="EnforcementDeadline"
    Expression={
        if($_.FeatureType -eq 2 -or $_.FeatureType -eq 7) {
            #Package or task sequence
            #Get assignment-starttime (ignoring daily/hourly etc.)
            (Get-CMPackageDeployment -DeploymentId $_.DeploymentID).AssignedSchedule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartTime
        } else {
            #Application
            $_.EnforcementDeadline
        }
    }
}

Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "abc" | select CollectionName, ApplicationName, PackageID, DeploymentTime, $DeadlineColumn | out-gridview
```

Comment: Trying a workaround, if i do : "Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "abc" | Format-List -Property *" I get a ton of other properties but still only "DeploymentTime 
ModificationTime  
SummarizationTime" no required time to be found. Yet it's there in SCCM GUI?

Comment: From Microsoft forums I was able to determine that "EnforcementDeadline" is the property that shows "required" time. However it's blank in my case even though a time was clearly set in SCCM Console....Any idea?

Comment: The Get() method doesn't work unfortunatly although i've read it should work in other articles? It returns : Cannot find an overload for "Get" and the argument count: "0".

Comment: I got access to an SCCM environment to test now so I could understand your problem better. The `Get()` is only required when using WMI it seems. See if the sample above can help you.

Comment: F, thank you this is exactly the explanation I needed to clearly understand what is going on and much appreciated to have a sample of code I will try to work something out with this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Frode F. I can't being to thank you enough, this is so perfect and time saving. Here is my final solution:

```
$DeadlineColumn = @{
    Name="EnforcementDeadline"
    Expression={
        if($_.FeatureType -eq "2" -or $_.FeatureType -eq "TaskSequence") {

            (Get-CMPackageDeployment -DeploymentId $_.DeploymentID).AssignedSchedule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartTime
        } else {
            (Get-CMTaskSequenceDeployment -DeploymentId $_.DeploymentID).AssignedSchedule | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartTime
        }
    }
}


$ExpirationColumn = @{
    Name="ExpirationTime"
    Expression={
        if($_.FeatureType -eq "2" -or $_.FeatureType -eq "TaskSequence") {

            (Get-CMPackageDeployment -DeploymentId $_.DeploymentID).ExpirationTime 
        } else {
             (Get-CMTaskSequenceDeployment -DeploymentId $_.DeploymentID).ExpirationTime 
        }
    }
}

Get-CMDeployment -CollectionName "gar25*" | select CollectionName, ApplicationName, PackageID, DeploymentTime, $DeadlineColumn, $ExpirationColumn | out-gridview
```

Which returns all times for packages and deployments!

[image]